# Shake does not recognize wether to build a rule/always builds a rule even if it shouldn't

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I have a project where I use shake to generate a bunch of reports based on input-files, and run as a restful webservice. One reason why I chose Shake is that is should not rebuild anything if input-files have not changed (e.g. based on Digest, configurable via `shakeOptions`).

I noticed that the processes would run even if I had just built them and no file change had happened in between runs. So I tried a simple example it should simulate the process of one of my builds

```
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Development.Shake

wanted = "foo.3"

main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want [wanted]                                       -- (1)
  "*.1" %> \out -> do                                 -- (2)
    liftIO $ putStrLn out
    unit $ cmd Shell "touch" "foo.2"

  "*.2" %> \out -> do need [out]                      -- (3)
                      unit $ cmd "touch" wanted

  action $ unit $ cmd Shell "touch" wanted            -- (4)
```

while the `%>` rules never run - the `action` rule is always done.

If I comment out (4) and create a file "foo.1" manually - the rule (1) is failing because it does not figure out that (2) -> (3) can build the result.

If on the other hand I comment out (2) and (3) and leave (4) - the rule runs even if "foo.3" exists and has been "built" by shake before.

I am using shake-0.15.11 in combination with shake - using `shake runhaskell Main.hs --package shake` or `shake exec -- testshake` does not make any difference. Compiler is GHC-8.0.2. All of this is done on a Linux (Mint).

I read [How does Shake decide whether to rebuild a target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469233) - from which I gathered that shake rebuilds stuff only if either the input-file(s) or the output-file change (where change is determined by the `shakeOptions` configuration)

Comment: You have strange build rules. (2) dosn't build `out`. (3) rule, instead of building an `out`, asks for it on input (need [out]).

Comment: I thought I might have a bit of a misunderstanding - If I build `out` - how  is the name of `out` determined? I thought `out` is the out-put of the pattern match on the lhs

Comment: The build rule (2) can build any file witch file path has extension ".1". It's mean that if some one call `need ["xxx.1"]` then will be run (2) build rule with `out = "xxx.1"`. If, for example, in the build rule (2) you need file with extension ".2", you can write: `need [out -<.> ".2"]`, after this it will be accessed.

Comment: AAAH now I got it! and what about `action`s - are they wildcard rules and run every time I call shake

Comment: Yes. And `want` defined like this: `want = action . need`

Comment: do you `action . need` to make your comments in answer? I would accept it.

Comment: Well, I'll try to sum up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `pat %> act` mean that you create the file-build-rule, which will be run for any file path witch will be accepted with the pattern `pat`. It's mean that if some one call `need [foo]` and `pat ?== foo` then will be run the action `act` with argument `foo`. So, the action `act` should to try build `foo`.

Secondly, about `action`, as wrote in the documentation:

> The action will be run in every build execution (unless withoutActions is used).

And `wand` defined like this: `want = action . need`.

For example, I redesign your example with some assumptions about dependencies between your files. Namely, foo.3 need foo.2, foo.2 need foo.1 and foo.1 already exists (it's source).

```
wanted = "foo.3"
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
    want [wanted]

    "*.3" %> \out -> do                      
        putNormal out
        need [out -<.> ".2"]
        unit $ cmd Shell "touch" out

    "*.2" %> \out -> do
        putNormal out
        need [out -<.> ".1"]
        unit $ cmd Shell "touch" out
```